# Eliminar espacios al final en cadena de texto con expresión regular

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, match

les expongo mi caso:

Tengo datos en el siguiente formato:

```
<td class=content valign=top align=left>1</td>
<td class=content valign=top align=left>2022-02-14</td>
<td class=content valign=top align=left>13.181       </td>
```

Y los datos que me interesan están dentro de las etiquetas HTML, por medio de REGEX me he dispuesto a recortar la información al interior de las etiquetas y he elaborado la siguiente expresión en Python:

```
"(?<=\>).*(?=<)"gm
```

La cual logra recortar el interior de las etiquetas pero me agarra los espacios en blanco que no quiero ni necesito, ejemplo:

Entrada:

```
<td class=content valign=top align=left>13.181       </td>
```

Salida:

```
"13.181         "
```

¿Saben qué le falta a mi expresión regular para eliminar los espacios al final de los que los contengan? Gracias.

Comment: strip() .......

Comment: Buen día, si alguna respuesta te fue útil no olvides aceptarla, de esa forma ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a preguntas similares y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

para eliminar los espacios al final puedes usar esta expresion:

```
"(?<=\>).*\S(?=\s*<)"gm
```

al hacerlo asi si lo que esta en el interior de las etiquetas esta vacio o solo contiene espacios, el regex no hace match

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, me sirvió, no había razonado esa forma de hacer el regex.

Answer (score 1):

Buen día,

Existen varias opciones para hacerlo. Tomando en cuenta que tu programa actual te devuelve `"13.181         "`

### Opción 1

Utilizar `replace`, con esto reemplazas los espacios en blanco `" "` por un string vacío `""`

### Opción 2

Utilizar `split`

### Opción 3

Utilizar expresiones regulares (Regex, del inglés Regular Expressions)

Te dejo un ejemplo con las 3 opciones:

```
import re

str = "13.181         "

#replace
print(str.replace(" ", ""))

#split
print("".join(str.split()))

#regex
print(re.sub(re.compile(r'\s+'), '', str))
```

La salida del programa es:

```
13.181
13.181
13.181
```

Comment: Tu respuesta está bien, lo único que yo le agregaría es un poco más de explicación de como funcionan las opciones 2 y 3. Imagina que los más novatos podrían no saber que hace split y join ni entender la regex. Además, hay que tener en cuenta que split también separa saltos de lineas.

Comment: Igual encontré un problema más, tu respuesta no responde a la pregunta, pues el OP pide eliminar los espacios al final, no todos los espacios. Y una ultima cosa, es recomendable evitar crear variables que se llamen igual que algo built-in de Python (como str), pues reemplazas el built-in por un valor. En lo personal, yo hago eso de llamar a la variable como algo built-in, pero siempre y cuando esté MUY seguro de que no usaré el built-in en ningún otro lado.